# Tailwindcss - Auto-add "tw-" prefix to existing codebase

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss

Tailwindcss has clear documentation on how one can generate prefixes for all tailwind classes to better isolate the styles of a particular app from its context. However,  I can't seem to find a straight answer on how I can transform the existing code to use the prefix. The documentation (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration) shows how to generate the "tw-" classes, but **not** how to modify the existing codebase to prepend this "tw-" prefix to the code itself. I have a lot of these classes and it isn't feasible to manually go through and add the "tw-" prefix to the existing classes. Am I missing something? How do I transform the existing codebase to use the generated class prefix without having to manually edit all tailwind classes myself?

Comment: Hi @camelCaseCowboy, please were you able to find a resolution on this? I am in the same boat currently.

Comment: I think the only thing you are missing is it is designed to be used from the outset of a project. If it is not feasible to update the existing codebase manually there are other ways to isolate the styles such as using `postcss-prefix-selector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use a VCS so you can revert everything if it goes wrong
2. Find a list of all tailwind classes. You can scrape https://tailwind.build/classes if you do not find a better source. The following snippet already works pretty well:

   ```js
   document.querySelectorAll("a.block").forEach(elem => {
       if (elem.innerText.startsWith(".")){
           console.log(elem.innerText);
       }
   });
   ```
3. Build a script that iterates over all class names and runs a recursive search-and-replace on your codebase
4. Review the diff and test your project thoroughly before committing